# Decode base64 images using a loop

Tags: python, loops, encoding, base64, decoding

I have an unknown number of images which were encoded using base64.  They are in the following format:

image0 = """\  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  """

image1 = """\  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  """

image2 = """\  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  """

I can successfully decode them using:

```
    imageToShow = base64.b64decode(image0)
    stream1 = cStringIO.StringIO(imageToShow)
    bmp1 = wx.ImageFromStream(stream1)
    self.image_spot0.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(bmp1))

    imageToShow = base64.b64decode(image1)
    stream1 = cStringIO.StringIO(imageToShow)
    bmp1 = wx.ImageFromStream(stream1)
    self.image_spot1.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(bmp1))

    imageToShow = base64.b64decode(image2)
    stream1 = cStringIO.StringIO(imageToShow)
    bmp1 = wx.ImageFromStream(stream1)
    self.image_spot2.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(bmp1))
```

Since there could be 3, 100, 300 or hey why not 5000 encoded images, I would like to be able to process the decoding using a loop.

When I attempted using the following code:

```
    image_group = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2']
    for img in image_group:
        imageToShow = base64.b64decode(img)
```

I get a padding error, I assume that the data is not passing to base64.b64decode(), only the actually string "image0".  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You call it in a loop like `base64.b64decode("image0")`, not with variable value. Hence your question could be reduced to "How can I evaluate/get value of local variable by its name". But I'd suggest declare those base64 strings in array for easier handling.

Comment: @kirilloid.  Thank you for the response. What you suggest is the code that I already have working, sans the quotes. That works fine if I can be sure ahead of time how many strings or at least the upper limit of strings that I will have to process. I am trying to be able to process a varying number of strings each time the code runs. Can you elaborate on how declaring the strings in an array may provide a solution?

Comment: Actually you can write `image_group = [image0, image1, image2]` and that should work.

Comment: @kirilloid.  Success!!  I love the answers that make you go duh!!  LOL  Thanks much, that was the last piece I needed.  Now since this was my first time posting a question, let me see how I mark it solved or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed up variable name string literal with same value.

The solution is in writing:

```
image_group = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2']
```

You can even reduce it by combining declarations like:

```
image_group = [
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA...",
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA...",
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA..."
]
```